# Format all dates inside IActionFilter

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, reflection, .net-core

I have a simple requirement, but it has been over one day and i cannot figure out what would be a good approach to do it. Here is the requirement:

> Whenever my service layer returns a dto, I want to be able to update all "DateTime" fields by adding one hour.

The best idea that i could of was to have Action Filter and apply it globally, so all dates are updated.

I also tried to use reflection since at runtime I will not be able to determine what Type I might have.

Here is my code:

```
  public class dtFilter : IActionFilter
    {
        public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {

        }

        public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
        {
            var datetimesKeyValue = context.ModelState.Keys;//.Result;//.ActionArguments.Where(p => p.Value is DateTime).ToList();

            var result = ((context.Result as ObjectResult)?.Value as ApiOkResponse)?.Result;

            var resulType = result.GetType();

            var resultProperties = resulType.GetProperties();


            foreach (var resultProperty in resultProperties)
            {
                Type mainProperty = resultProperty.PropertyType;
                if (mainProperty.IsClass)
                {
                    GetPropertiesAndUpdateDate(mainProperty, resultProperty.PropertyType);

                }
            }

        }

        private static void GetPropertiesAndUpdateDate(Type mainProperty, Type resultProperty)
        {
            var properties = mainProperty.GetProperties();
            foreach (var propertyInfo in properties)
            {
                if (propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsClass)
                {
                    GetPropertiesAndUpdateDate(propertyInfo.PropertyType, propertyInfo.DeclaringType);
                }

                if (propertyInfo.PropertyType.Name == "DateTime")
                {
                    PropertyInfo fieldPropertyInfo = mainProperty.GetProperties()
                        .FirstOrDefault(f => string.Equals(f.Name, propertyInfo.Name, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));

                    fieldPropertyInfo.SetValue(resultProperty, DateTime.Now);
                }
                Debug.Write("s");
            }
        }
```

The problem is at the SetValue, I am getting the error

> System.Reflection.TargetException: 'Object does not match target type.'

Any help is appreciated please

Comment: Have you verified that the type of `resultProperty` is `DateTime` when this fails?

Comment: It is failing on   fieldPropertyInfo.SetValue(resultProperty, DateTime.Now); do you think i should use typeof(DateTime) instead of resultProperty?

Comment: What is the reason you want to add an hour?

Comment: The best way is create a function CovertToUserTimezone(), and use in all places. What are you going to do when you will need to convert to few different time zones. Also, using reflection is not good way

Comment: I totally agree, that was my initial thought, but then I thought it would be a good option to use a filter, that would convert to user timezone globally without having to specify this function every where.

Comment: GetPropertiesAndUpdateDate method should depends on object that you return.

Comment: You shouldn't care what is user timezone, return all dates as UTC dates and users can convert it in the timezones they need. This is client responsibility.

Comment: @Fabio need to convert to user's city time zone. So say user moves to another city, we still want to convert it to his home city time zone only , not the city he has moved to. Now, either I send the offset with each response, or convert it at server side and send him his home city date time.

Comment: Then it looks more like a business logic, which shouldn't be at infrastructure level, but instead you should have a method which will do this conversion in the domain logic - requires maybe more work now, but give you full power of changes later regardless of current technology you are using for application hosting.

Comment: Perfect . thanks I understood now

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a `PropertyInfo` object as the first argument of `SetValue`. However, the first parameter should be the object on which you want to set the property value.

If you had a property `DateTime Target` in an object `MyClass` you would call `SetValue` as:

```c#
var propertyInfo = myClassInstance.GetType().GetProperty("Target");
propertyInfo.SetValue(myClassInstance, DateTime.Now, null);
```